# roll backin all the records in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

My interviewer asked me Question that i am inserting 10 rows in database table and in some 5th row i find the some trouble then how can i roll back all the records?

Please let me know how can i do this

Comment: Answer is "I wrap the 10 inserts in a transaction"

Answer (score 5):

Assuming all occur within the same transaction, use the `ROLLBACK` command.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this twice, once for the right answer and another for the lol I had when I read your name. :-D

Answer (score 1):

Before you insert the rows

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION TransactionName
```

[Insert Rows]

Then either

```
COMMIT TRANSACTION TransactionName
```

OR

```
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION TransactionName
```

during any problems during the insert.